# How to disable <br> tags inside <div> by css?

Tags: html, css

`<br>` won't let me to display 3 buttons inline, so i need to disable it inside div, and I can't just delete them, they are automatically there.

I have:

```
<div style="display:block">
    <p>Some text</p>
    <br>
    <p>Some text</p>
    <br>
</div>
```

and I want:

```
<div style="display:block">
    Some text Some text
</div>
```

**More info**

I do not want to have mystyle.css file.
Of course I know that way of disabling it.

I asked how to add to divs style this `br { display: none; }` if it is possible.

**Solution:**

1. It is not possible to remove just `<p>` tags without removing content inside.
2. It is not possible to hide `<br>` directly by divs style, so I make it this way:

> ```
> <style type="text/css">
> .mydiv {
> display: block;
> width: 100%;
> height: 10px;
> }
> .mydiv br {
> display: none;
> }
> </style>
>     
> <div class="mydiv">
> Some text
> Some text
> </div>
> ```

http://jsfiddle.net/cGT4E/

Comment: Just remove the tags then ;) What are you expecting CSS to do about it? This question makes no sense...

Comment: You want to remove HTML Elements via CSS? Not possible.

Comment: *"messing my css"* isn't really a valid problem. What **specifically** is the problem?

Comment: In addition to the comment of F4r-20. You should explain why they exist and where you get the data form. Because you could either filter when you get the data, prevent the creation of them or change the way they are styled to prevent the _messing of the css_

Comment: @bottleboot No, he won't need jquery. If you think he will *need*, please give your reasons.

Comment: There is br { display: none; }, I just do not know how to use it inside style="" and not class=""

Comment: And should never have a `<br />` after a `<p>` tage, you would get the spacing you need by applying `margin-bottom:10px` to `<p>` tags in css

Comment: @destroy why not? he wants to remove <p> tags (see the given example) You can't do that with css. You can do that with JS and Jquery fairly easy

Comment: If they are getting generated dynamically, then you also might get a `class` or `id` respectively with this dynamic generation. Just take that `id` or `class` and apply `display:none;` for the `p` and `br` tags. For Instance, if the div id is `abc`, then use this in your css. `#abc br {display:none;}`. Thats it.

Comment: @NathanLee He wants the content inside the tags to still be visible.

Comment: @bottleboot He doesn't want to remove the p element. And he wouldn't even **need** jquery for that. All what can be done with jQuery can be done without it.

Comment: Might I ask: How comes you can alter css, add style and so on, but not remove html tags? This does not make any sense

Comment: @dystroy the code block underneath ```and I want``` has the <p> tags removed, seems like he wants them gone

Comment: If you want to disable it, just use an `<input>` tag. For instance, `<input type="text" disabled="disabled" title="Text" value="Text" style="border:none; background:transparent;" />`. Thats it. But I still don't understand why he wants `<br>` also disabled?? What will that do??

Comment: Curiosity about not important is more important than what is actually important on stackoverflow. I need <br> disabled coz text or buttons or whatever is not in horizontal line, it is in "stoop style" with <br> inside when I float one, or div for each text line / button.

Comment: Aah.. You are making things too complicated for your code. - @PoloPakina

Comment: This question is particularly relavent in terms of responsive design these days. You might want certain `<br>` tags disabled only at certain screen widths.

Answer (score 89, accepted):

You could alter your CSS to render them less obtrusively, e.g.

```
div p,
div br {
    display: inline;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/zG9Ax/

or - as  my commenter points out:

```
div br {
    display: none;
}
```

but then to achieve the example of what you want, you'll need to trim the `p` down, so:

```
div br {
    display: none;
}
div p {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/zG9Ax/1

Comment: You should use `display:none` for `br` if you want to remove them.

Comment: True. http://jsfiddle.net/zG9Ax/1/ slightly more code though. Just pointing in a possible direction here.

Answer (score 5):

I used this and it had the effect of removing the line break and showing it as a space between words. I think this is closer to what you were looking for.

```
br {
  display: inline;
  content: ' ';
  padding: 0 3px;
}
```

Comment: It's interesting that the `content` property is needed for the `display: inline;` to work. How did you figure that out and any idea why that is so?

Comment: You can leave out the content property but then the next word will be right up against the previous word. The content:' ' prop with display:inline acts like a non breaking space.

Comment: Hello David, I used this promising answer but it doesn't work on Firefox (100.0b5 (64-bit)) and Safari unfortunately (Version 15.4 (17613.1.17.1.13))

Answer (score 4):

or hide any br that follows the p tag, which are obviously not wanted

```
p + br {
    display: none;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
<p style="color:black">Shop our collection of beautiful women's <br> <span> wedding ring in classic &amp; modern design.</span></p>
```

Remove `<br>` effect using CSS.

```
<style> p br{ display:none; } </style>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use`display:contents`, but avoid accessibility problems to apply this only on `br` tags:

```css
br {
  display:contents;
}
```

see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/display-box

> [display:contents;] most browsers will remove from the accessibility tree any element with a display value of contents. [...] no longer be announced by screen reading technology.

Answer (score 1):

I came across the same problem and solved it with `display: contents`

Here is the demo:

```css
.wrapper {
  background: #EEE;
  overflow: hidden;
  white-space: nowrap;
  text-overflow:ellipsis;
}

.wrapper * {
  display:contents;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <p>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit,<br/>
    sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.  <br/>
    Pretium lectus quam id leo in vitae turpis massa sed. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipiscing elit.<br/>
    Sagittis id consectetur purus ut faucibus pulvinar elementum. Netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas sed.<br/>
    Eget duis at tellus at.
  </p>
  <p>
    Faucibus vitae aliquet nec ullamcorper sit amet risus. Tortor condimentum lacinia quis vel eros donec ac.<br/>
    Tellus in hac habitasse platea dictumst vestibulum. Aliquam id diam maecenas ultricies. Tortor id aliquet lectus proin nibh nisl condimentum id.<br/>
    Sed enim ut sem viverra. <br/> 
    Morbi tristique senectus et netus et.
  </p>
</div>
```

So according to MDN,

> These elements don't produce a specific box by themselves. They are replaced by their pseudo-box and their child boxes.

What makes it worthy, (again taken from MDN)

> Please note that the CSS Display Level 3 spec defines how the contents value should affect "unusual elements"

Here **CSS Display Level 3 spec** says, certain elements are rendered as `display: none` if `display:contents` applies to them:

> `<br>`
> `<wbr>`
> `<meter>`
> `<progress>`
> `<canvas>`
> `<embed>`
> `<object>`
> `<audio>`
> `<iframe>`
> `<img>`
> `<video>`
> `<frame>`
> `<frameset>`
> `<input>`
> `<textarea>`
> `<select>`
>
> `display: contents` computes to `display: none`.

(source: https://drafts.csswg.org/css-display/#unbox)

Answer (score 0):

I used it like this:

```
@media (max-width: 450px) {
  br {
    display: none;
  }
}
```

nb: media query via Foundation
nb2: this is useful if one of the editor intend to use 
 tags in his/her copy and you need to deal with it specifically under some conditions—on mobile for example.

Answer (score 0):

I see people commenting just to remove from the html, but if you want to remove it only from certain type of @media screens, then this is the way to go:

```
div br {
  display: none;
}
```

Comment: This is not valid HTML or CSS.

Comment: how so? I applied it to my css and it worked.

Comment: CSS does not have a 'nested selector' feature (outside of media queries or the keyframe steps of an animation). I'm guessing you are using a preprocessor like Sass or Less and not considering that before compiling it into CSS (where it would compile to something like `div br { display: none; }`.

Comment: oh I see what you meant. Yes, I am using a preprocessor. - appreciate the info. I'll take down my comment.

Comment: This is actually a good idea.