# Replacing <br> within a table, using css

Tags: html, css

Is there a way to replace < br > tags within a table with another char or a string? I can't access the table itself, but i can use CSS to decide how how this table is being displayed. I would like < br> tags outside the table to work properly. White-space with it's property values doesn't seem to work. Is it even possible to do this?

Sorry if I didn't mention something important, I'm new to CSS.

Comment: No, there is not. You would need something scripty to do this ;)

Comment: BR generates a line-break and it is only a line-break. As this element has no content, there are only few styles that make sense to apply on it, like clear or position. You could for example set BR's border but you won't see it as it has no visual dimension.

Comment: Are you actually wanting to replace the `<br>`s or just stopping them causing line breaks?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to disable <br> tags inside <div> by css?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17588953/how-to-disable-br-tags-inside-div-by-css)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change a `<br>` tag to a character like this:

```
<style>
br {
    content: "";
}
br:after {
    content: ",";
}
</style>

test <br> test
```

In my example I decided to display a comma.

Comment: I tried combining your answer with Billy's answer and information from thread mentioned by Casey Rule. I needed <br > tags changed only within a certain table. So I added 

`.tablename br { content: " "; }
.tablename br:after {content: ", ";}` 

to my < style > section and it works fine in Chrome and Opera, but it doesn't work in Firefox. Is there a solution to this, maybe it's caused by incorrect < style > formatting or maybe Firefox doesn't support this tag?

Answer (score 0):

You can hide it with following CSS

```
br {
    display: none;
}
```

Comment: This doesn't replace it with another character or string, as the question asks.

Answer (score 0):

```css
table br{display:none;}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>Long text with a br<br> tag</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
<p>
  A long paragraph with a br in A long paragraph with a br in A long paragraph with a br in A long paragraph with a br in A long paragraph with a br in A long paragraph with a br in A long paragraph with a br in A long paragraph with a br in A long paragraph with a br in A long paragraph with a br in A long paragraph with a br in A long paragraph with a br in A long paragraph with a br in A long paragraph with a br in A long paragraph with a br in A long paragraph with a br in A long paragraph with a br in A long paragraph with a br in A long paragraph with a br in A long paragraph with a br in A long paragraph with a br in A long paragraph with a br in A long paragraph with a br <br><br>in A long paragraph with a br in A long paragraph with a br in A long paragraph with a br in A long paragraph with a br in A long paragraph with a br in A long paragraph with a br in A long paragraph with a br in A long paragraph with a br in A long paragraph with a br in A long paragraph with a br in A long paragraph with a br in</p>
```